# When and how is constructor called when passing arguments by reference?

Tags: c++

I have the following program

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0)
        : m_n(n)
    {
        std::cout << 'd';
    }

    A(const A& a)
        : m_n(a.m_n)
    {
        std::cout << 'c';
    }

private:
    int m_n;
};

void f(const A &a1, const A &a2 = A())
{
}

int main()
{
    f(3);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This program produces "dd" as output. I don't understand why constructor is called for the first parameter of the function "f". I am passing it an integer "3" and it calls constructor for "a1" with argument "3". How is this happening ?

Comment: The copy c'tor isn't called. The "convert from int" c'tor is called.

Comment: where do you see the copy c'tor being called? `c` is not included in the output.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Nothing appears to be strange or confusing here and you haven't told us what it is that you find odd.

Answer (score 2):

This constructor

```
A(int n = 0)
    : m_n(n)
{
    std::cout << 'd';
}
```

is a conversion constructor. It converts an object of type int (in this case this object is specified by parameter n) to an object of type A. So when you call function f as

```
f( 3 );
```

the compiler sees that there is a function with such name that has the first parameter of type const A &. So it tries to convert 3 to an object of type A and it can do this due to the conversion constructor that it calls implicitly. Then a reference to this temporary object is passed to the function. If you would declare the constructor as

```
explicit A(int n = 0)
    : m_n(n)
{
    std::cout << 'd';
}
```

then the compiler could not call it implicitly and issue an error.

As for the second parameter then it has a default argument: an temporary object of type A. The compiler can bind a const reference to a temporary object.

So in your code the conversion constructor is called twice. For the first argument it is called implicitly by the compiler and for the second argument it is called explicitly because its call is specified as the default argument.
The copy constructor does not take part in this process. You do not copy any object. You only bind temporary objects with const references.

Answer (score 1):

`A::A(int n);` gets called with `n` set to `3`. The object is a temporary which is passed to `f` which takes it by a const reference to `A`.

In your code the copy constructor never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler tries to match function parameter with what was given. He got `int 3` but needs either `A(int n)` or `A(const A& a)`. Compiler then notes that he can easily create temporary object `A` that takes and `int` and feed that to the function. So that's what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The copy constructor isn't called at all, for the run that produced your output.

<del>And the explanation of that is that the copy constructor call (for the second argument) was *elided*, optimized away.</del> The explanation is that both formal arguments are references, as implicitly pointed out by Steve Jessop in comments (I was a bit blind there).

Both the first and second formal arguments of `f` are constructed with calls to the `int` argument constructor, since it doubles as default constructor.

Comment: Are you sure that there is copy constructor elision for the second argument? I don't think that the implementation is permitted to call the copy constructor for this code.

Comment: @SteveJessop: oh, it's a reference. didn't see that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you pass objects around by value, the copies are created using one of the available constructors. That may be a copy constructor (that takes an `A` and results in another `A`) or it may be a constructor that takes something completely different (and results in an `A`)!

This is a basic fact of object construction and has nothing to do with references:

```
struct A
{
   A(int x) {};
};

void foo(A a) {}

int main()
{
   foo(3);  // OK
}
```

In your case you're not passing by value, *but* C++ still tries to form a `A` for you in order to get your function call to work. When successful (as here), the result is a temporary `A` (which can be bound to the `const` reference).

Ultimately, this is like:

```
int main()
{
   A a(3);
   foo(a);
}
```

Being able to pass things into function calls that then have conversions applied is a crucial tool in C++'s flexibility.